# React Activate the button with one click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are four buttons.
You can currently move the link with one click.
However, you need to double-click the button to activate the color of the button.

I want to activate the link and button with a click.
Would it be possible to get some help?

**Sidebar.js**

```
const [selectBtn, setSelectBtn] = useState();

{SETTING_BAR_ICON.map(data => {
       return (
        <SidebarIcon
         key={data.id}
         src={data.img}
         select={data.select}
         link={data.link}
         handleChangeBtnColor={() => 
         setSelectBtn(data.id)}
         isSelectBtn={selectBtn === data.id}
         />
        );
       })}
```

**SidebarIcon.js**

```
<SidebarIconContainer>
      {isSelectBtn ? (
        <ImgBackground>
          <ImgSelect src={select} />
          <ImgText>{link}</ImgText>
        </ImgBackground>
      ) : (
        <Link to={`/${link}`}>
          <ImgFormat src={src} onClick=. 
          {handleChangeBtnColor} />
        </Link>
      )}
</SidebarIconContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue you never close the function curly bracket in the `handleChangeBtnColor` property of the `SidebarIcon`. You need a `}` before the `/>`. You also need the two methods inside to be wrapped in  curly brackets. When you use arrow functions use curly brackets all the time, lie this:

```
const doSomething = () => {
  ...
}
```

Unless you only have one thing to return inside then you can leave out the curly bracket like this:

```
// shorthand
const doSomething = () => doAThing()
const getSomething = () => 'thing'

// same as this
const doSomething = () => {
  return doAThing()
}
const getSomething = () => {
  return 'thing'
}

// if you go to the next line you should use parenthesis
const doSomething = () => (
  doAThing()
)
```

But I don't think that will fix it. Rather than use a `Link` tag, use the `useNavigation` hook and change the path in the `handleChange...` function. So something like this:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate()

return (
  <SidebarIcon
    ...
    handleChangeBtnColor={(link) => {
      setSelectBtn(data.id)
      isSelectBtn={selectBtn === data.id}
      navigate(`/${link}`)
    }}
  />
)
```

```
<DivStyledLikeYourOtherLinks onClick={() => handleChangeBtnColor(link)} />
```